# Django forms cleaned data

Tags: django, forms

I have a written library for application.

Library methods accepts ids of objects of integer type. 
Instead of User objects it accepts username and so on.

Where i have to convert the data from my forms into proper type?

Can i do this in clean methods of my forms or i should do this in my views?
Does it follows the rules or clean method is used only for validation?

```
def clean_object_id(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['object_id']:
        return int(self.cleaned_date['object_id'])
```

Comment: `clean_field_name` is used both for validation and conversions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw examples for validation but didnt saw for conversions, that's why i asked